# Android database storage formats appropriate for JavaScript access

Tags: javascript, android, database, sqlite

I'm developing an Android application, typically with a fairly small database (hundreds to a thousand or so main entries, plus similar order of magnitude in joined tables) populated by the user. There is also a file associated with each main entry, but those are kept separate, and not part of this question.

In my current prototype, the structured data is stored in a SQLite database in the usual way, and synced between devices by uploading the file to an Application Folder on Google Drive. This allows me to avoid having to provide any user storage, which is something I hope to stick to.

Storing files here also has the happy side effect that I can access them via JavaScript code in a web page using the Google Drive API. But JavaScript interacting with a remote SQLite file is an incredibly ugly thing to attempt. (Downloading the database server-side and handling it there is another option which sounds not great either.) I am wondering if anyone has any recommendations of the best practice approach here, given I would like to have a web-based version of the app accessing the same data.

The obvious most sensible idea seems to be

> Exporting from SQLite to some other structured format *XXX* (like XML, JSON, CSV, ...) first, uploading that *XXX* file to Google Drive, so that JavaScript can straightforwardly interact with it, and then on sync reimporting this *XXX* data back into SQLite.

though I'm happy to hear any criticisms/improvements on this idea.

I'm mainly interested in best-practice recommendations of efficient ways to approach these problems. Question: **What file format *XXX* would be good; and do you have any recommended methods for (a) exporting and importing in Java from SQLite to *XXX*, (b) interacting in preferably client-side JavaScript with a remote Google Drive file in format XXX?** (If maintaining server-side code to interact with *XXX* is substantially better practice do say.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many clients your app will manage

> Exporting from SQLite to some other structured format XXX (like XML, JSON, CSV, ...) first, uploading that XXX file to Google Drive, so that JavaScript can straightforwardly interact with it, and then on sync reimporting this XXX data back into SQLite.

IMHO, this is quite a bad idea for quite a few reasons:

1. If multiple users try to change data at the same time, you will have a tough problem managing all those data entries and possible conflicts
2. Providing direct access to your data layer is ALWAYS a bad idea since any client can wipe out all your data

If you have very few users or are making it as a personal project, you can stick with SQLite.

Kripken, the developer of Emscripten (the C/C++ to Javascript LLVM compiler) has compiled the SQLite Library to Javascript to make the `sql.js` library. You can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js/). There's also a [demo page of sql.js](http://kripken.github.io/sql.js/GUI/)

But if you have a lot of users, you might want to use [Firebase by Google](https://firebase.google.com/). It gives you a database and a REST API to use it. There are [libraries to access Firebase from different programming languages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/) too.

Cheers!